# Chroma Key using Core Image filters leaves a halo around text

Tags: objective-c, graphics, core-image, chromakey

I have been trying to come up with a simple way to use Core Image filters to key out the background of a slide and to key out text of a certain color. My current project works, but with one caveat: the text that I am trying to remove is gone, but a halo remains.

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

From what I can tell, there is a blue halo around the "Main Slide Content", but this is probably okay since the main content is still on the screen. I want to remove the halo around the "Test Speaker Notes", though, because that's intended to be entirely keyed out.

In my head, I feel like the solution would be to get a mask of the green text, and then expand that mask a little bit, and then use that in a multiply filter to key out the halos, but I don't know how to approach this with Core Image. I would appreciate any guidance on which path to take here. Here is my applicationDidFinishLaunching method and the keying and blending methods, which are the two methods that do the work. All code is in the project file on GitHub, found [here]: https://github.com/nspaul/chromakeytest

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"testSlide.png"];
    NSImage *actsBG = [NSImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
    NSImage *keyed = img;

    //Key out the green
    keyed = [self keyImage:keyed minHue:0.25 maxHue:0.4];

    //Key out the blue background
    keyed = [self keyImage:keyed minHue:0.6 maxHue:0.7];

    //Put the test slide over the background slide
    keyed = [self blendImage:keyed withBackgroundImage:actsBG];

    [_topImageView setImage:img];
    [_backgroundImageView setImage:actsBG];
    [_keyedImageView setImage:keyed];
}




-(NSImage *)blendImage:(NSImage *)img withBackgroundImage:(NSImage *)bgimg {
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:[img TIFFRepresentation]];
    CIImage *bgInputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:[bgimg TIFFRepresentation]];
    CIFilter *blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];

    [blendFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [blendFilter setValue:bgInputImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [blendFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    NSImage *resultImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[outputImage extent].size];
    NSCIImageRep *rep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:outputImage];
    [resultImage addRepresentation:rep];

    return resultImage;
}



-(NSImage *) keyImage:(NSImage *)imageToKey minHue:(float)minHueAngle maxHue:(float)maxHueAngle {
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:[imageToKey TIFFRepresentation]];


    // Allocate memory
    const unsigned int size = 64;
    float *cubeData = (float *)malloc (size * size * size * sizeof (float) * 4);
    float rgb[3], hsv[3], *c = cubeData;

    // Populate cube with a simple gradient going from 0 to 1
    for (int z = 0; z < size; z++){
        rgb[2] = ((double)z)/(size-1); // Blue value
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
            rgb[1] = ((double)y)/(size-1); // Green value
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x ++){
                rgb[0] = ((double)x)/(size-1); // Red value
                // Convert RGB to HSV
                // You can find publicly available rgbToHSV functions on the Internet
                rgbToHSV(rgb, hsv);
                // Use the hue value to determine which to make transparent
                // The minimum and maximum hue angle depends on
                // the color you want to remove
                float alpha = (hsv[0] > minHueAngle && hsv[0] < maxHueAngle) ? 0.0f: 1.0f;
                // Calculate premultiplied alpha values for the cube
                c[0] = rgb[0] * alpha;
                c[1] = rgb[1] * alpha;
                c[2] = rgb[2] * alpha;
                c[3] = alpha;
                c += 4; // advance our pointer into memory for the next color value
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"cubeData: %p",cubeData);

    // Create memory with the cube data
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cubeData
                                        length:(64 * 64 * 64 * sizeof (float) * 4)
                                  freeWhenDone:YES];
    CIFilter *colorCube = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorCube"];
    [colorCube setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:size] forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
    // Set data for cube
    [colorCube setValue:data forKey:@"inputCubeData"];


    [colorCube setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    CIImage *outImage = [colorCube valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

    NSImage *resultImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[outImage extent].size];
    NSCIImageRep *rep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:outImage];
    [resultImage addRepresentation:rep];

    return resultImage;
}
```

Comment: Where are these slides coming from? Why do you need to key things out as a post process? If you're drawing the slides, just draw the background first, then draw the text over it.

Comment: Looks like there is a shadow on the notes text. These problems could be caused by compression artefacts.